# How to show "1 of 5" at bottom ViewPager Android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, indicator

I'm beginner with Android, I use ViewPager with 5 fragments, and I want to show position of fragment like "1 of 5" when fragment 1 is selected, how can I do?
Thanks for all support!

Comment: you can use any page indicator lib one of these https://github.com/chenupt/SpringIndicator

Comment: use viewpagerindicator you can take a help from here   http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-jake-wharton-viewpager-indicator-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

you can use `viewPager.getCurrentItem()` to get current item of view pager and then you can use that value in textview as

```
textview.setText(viewPager.getCurrentItem()+" of 5");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add to your ViewPager a `OnPageChangeListener`, `onPageSelected(int position)` will be called when a page is shown in the pager. There you should access your pages indicator in order to change the current page.

```
 addOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                // Not used
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // Logic to update indicator labels.
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                // Not used
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a textview at the bottom of your viewpager and there you can use

```
 viewpager.getCurrentItem();
```

If you have a pageListener attached to your viewpager , you can also change it in onPageSelected method.